# How to access Sinatra Logger from a model?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Within a request, the Sinatra logger works fine:

```
get '/' do
  logger.info "loading data"
  ...
```

However, from within a model, it doesn't work. The model does not have access to the logger:

```
class Foo
  def self.do_something
    logger.info "loading data"
  end
end

get '/' do
  Foo.do_something
  ...
```

How to access the logger from within a model?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you want to do

```
class Foo < Sinatra::Base
```

because logger is not available in the scope of the Foo class as you defined it.

Answer (score 1):

@Bjoern's answer will work, but I suppose that would make `Foo` a controller and not a model. Another way would be to initialise a logger before Sinatra sets one up for you and then pass it to it to use. One way of doing this could be:

```
class Foo
  def self.logger
    @logger ||= Logger.new STDOUT
  end
end

configure do
  set :logger, Foo.logger
end
```